# How to look through log files in console or Terminal to find if a USB/external hard drive was mounted?

Tags: usb

I use Big Sur. I'm looking for any USB/external hard drive mounts in my computer from the last 30 days. I tried searching for " USBMSC" in my console log files for the day, when I knew there was at least one mount that day, but nothing came up, so it's inaccurate. Where/how can I accurately find USB/external hard drive mounts in Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
log show --debug --last 30d --predicate "sender == 'Sandbox' AND eventMessage matches 'identified disk[0-9]+ as removable'"
```

Note that this can take an **extremely** long time to run (several minutes per day of logging, i.e., **one hour or more** in your case!) due to the highly inefficient search algorithm used by the `log` command so if you don't need 30 days of history, you can reduce the number specified in the `--last XXXd` argument or use the `--start` and/or `--end` arguments to specify start and end timestamp ranges, respectively. See `man log` and `log help show` for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much! How do I find the system log files from the last 60 days?

Comment: @mouse1985 I mean, just change the 30 to a 60 :) Or are you asking a more general question about *any* logs? If so, then I believe you've already asked that question separately: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/433971/how-do-i-find-system-log-files-on-terminal-from-the-last-60-days-i-dont-have and the answer by @nohillside is basically correct: The system purges old logs and it's unlikely to have kept two months' worth. But you can use the `--start` and `--end` arguments and just remove `--predicate` to choose any date range to view. Again, see `man log` and `log help show`.

Comment: @mouse1985 If I have answered your original question to your satisfaction, would you kindly mark my answer as accepted? (Click the checkmark to the top-left of my answer.) Thank you!