# How do I find system log files on Terminal from the last 60 days? ( I don't have a backup)

Tags: terminal

How do I find system log files from the last 60 days on Terminal when I don't have a backup?

Comment: Search Ask Different for "I don't have a backup", and see all the avoidable problems you can have.

Answer (score 4):

macOS uses a rolling archive for system logs, keeping the 10 most recent logs available in `/var/log`. If you don't have a backup, anything older than that will not be available.